# Methods to detect touches on a coreplot graph

Tags: ios, touch, core-plot, detection

I've been looking into coreplot. I've got a graph plotted, but I'm looking to detect touches on it in a similar way to "touchesBegan" "touchesMoved" etc.

I've seen a lot of very vague stuff about the methods used such as

```
 "- plotSpace:shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:atPoint:"
```

But I'm getting nowhere with them. Any tips?

Comment: What is your goal?  Do you want to detect movement / swipe  or just a touch event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your header file, add the CPTPlotSpaceDelegate

```
@interface MyCorePlotView : UIView <CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate> {
    ...
}
```

In your implementation file add the delegate method

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    // Handle down event
}
```

When the user taps the plot area you will receive the plotSpace:shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent: and then you can take appropriate action.

Look in the CPTPlotSpace.h for other delegate methods you might want to use as well.

Comment: Could you form some kind of example? I'm not understanding what "plotSpace" actually is.

All I'm trying to do is output touch and move coordinates fyi.

Comment: plotSpace is just part of the method name.

Comment: Ah alright. xcode is seeing it as an "Undeclared identifier"? I guess it's not recognising the method then.

Comment: Could you be missing an #import "..." or do you need to add the protocols to your header <CPTPlotDataSource, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate>?  Also, that method isn't something you call directly.  Core Plot will call it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not missing #import and I'm not sure how to add the protocols to my header. As you may have guessed, I'm rather new to this coreplot business.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what I have to do to here? Or perhaps point me in the direction of some literature on touch detection for core plot?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It doesn't work as I think there's some issues that I can't see yet but will get to at some point.